# Can I monitor the progress of importing a large .sql file in sqlite3 using zenity --progress?

Tags: import, sqlite

I'm trying to monitor the progress of a sqlite3 command importing a large .sql file into a database using `zenity --progress`.

I've tried the following which will import the file, however progress is not shown:

```
sqlite3 DATABASE < import_file.sql | zenity --progress --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

I know I need to provide `zenity` a numeric source for the progress, but don't really know how to obtain the number.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite3` tool does not output such numbers.

You would have to write some script that feeds the lines of the import file into `sqlite3`, and at the same time feeds the percentage numbers into `zenity`. Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
maxlines=$(wc -l < import_file.sql)
exec 3> >(zenity --progress --auto-close)
counter=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    counter=$(($counter+1))
    echo $(($counter * 100 / $maxlines)) >&3
done < import_file.sql
```

Call it with `thescript | sqlite3 dbfile`.

Comment: I tried this out and the zenity bar seems to start about 4/5 of the way complete.  I tried initializing the zenity --progress bar at 0, but that didn't help either.

Comment: It's likely that the first lines in your file are executed faster.

Comment: I don't think so.  The entire file is one big mass of insert statements.  Nothing is different in the beginning.  Also, the zenity progress bar is at 100 percent after about 3-5 seconds, but the sqlite3 statement doesn't finish until a long time after.  Strange.

Comment: Output the percentages to the console (`>&2` instead of `>&3`) to check whether they are correct.

Comment: The numbers look correct.  It does the count from 0 to 100.  However, it's like the console won't kill the process when it's complete (even with --auto-kill).

Comment: Now works for me with `--auto-close`.